# Joining two plugins in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

I have created two different plugins in QGIS using Python. I would like to combine both in one plugin.

How can I do that?

Comment: What's exactly your problem? You can combine them creating, for instance, a toolbar, where each button corresponds to each plugin. Your logic would be handled by the slot connected to the "triggered()" signal of each button (action).

Answer (score 1):

Every plugin is a python module and every plugin is present in the PYTHONPATH, so you can import it as a python module.

e.g. if your plugin "myplugin" is in ~/.qis2/python/plugins/myplugin you can import with `from myplugin import <your class>` or `import myplugin` and use it as usual.

obviously would be a good sw design, strictly separate plugin logic from it's GUI, in this way you can use it's logic as python command.

regards